# Display icons in Django admin for each item

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-admin

I want to add a specified icon for each model on admin index page. I added an attribute named "picture" on each model then I modified /contrib/admin/sites.py to pass that picture name to template and checked and use it on index.html template of admin to get the result.
I wonder to know if there is a better way

```
class Product(models.Model):
    abbr = models.CharField(max_length=20,unique=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProxy)
    des = models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    picture =  'product.png'    
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.abbr
    class Meta:
        none
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What You did seems OK, only small tips that can make Your code a little better:

1. Instead of modifying `django/contrib/admin/sites.py` You can subclass the `AdminSite` class (if You didn't do that already).
2. Modify the `AdminSite.index()` method to pass not picture, but whole admin class (there is a `model_admin` variable available in the `index()` method).
3. Assign picture in the ModelAdmin classes, not models, to separate admin stuff from models.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from 'Python Fanboy' was so brief but useful to me, I could avoid modifying django base classes

1. picture field were moved to admin class
2. I subclass AdminSite as CustomAdminSite and copied index and app_index and made modification
   (I don't know if there is a better way than copying whole of index and app_index like overriding)
3. In urls.py, '`admin.sites.url`'  replaced by '`custom_site.url`'
   (`custom_site` is instance of `CustomAdminSite`)
4. I did not want another url instead of '`/admin`' like '`/my_admin`' so I have to use instance of `CustomAdminSite` for all my models even User, Group & Site
5. I'm using `admin_tools`, now I've lose my application menu

Any better Idea or solution for my new encountered problems?